# Google analytics API issue with domain name

Tags: google-api, dotnetnuke, google-analytics-api, google-code

I have a public facing site e.g. www.mysite.domain.com which I have registered under Google console API to get API_ID & Client_ID. Which I am using in my javascript.

Now I have another site which I have to specially use for reporting purpose e.g.  www.reports.domain.com. However when I use my - mywebsite API & ClientID  values on reporting site I am unable to see data.

Both sites are on same machine and same instance of application - DotNetNuke framework

Can anyone tell me what more I have to do, so that I can see data on one site on to another.

Thanks,

Avinash

Comment: Where are you addimg your Google Analytics javascript code?

Comment: I am trying to add javascript code under same page (.aspx) on both sites where charts are configured.
From DotNetNuke prospective, I am adding javascript code on main default.aspx page which is at root directory.